# Cup products and cross products

Tags: homology-cohomology

So, I am trying to compute some products on chains and their duals, but I have difficulties in understanding some operations.

The *cup product* of cochains is quite easy to understand, especially when computing them. However, I cannot grasp why starting from chains I hit a non-associative wall. Let me explain, if I have a duality $\phi : C_p \rightarrow C^p$ (on a complex $K$ with values in an abelian group $G$), I can in theory calculate a product of two chains on the same complex as
$$
c_k \cdot c_\ell = 
\sum_i (c^k \smile c^\ell)(\sigma_{i}) \sigma_{i}  = 
\sum_i \phi(c_k)(\sigma_i|_{v_0 \ldots v_k}) \cdot 
       \phi(c_\ell)(\sigma_i|_{v_k \ldots v_{k+\ell}}) \sigma_i 
\in C_{k+\ell},
$$

This seems to be non associative.

Am I doing something non kosher here? I expected to be able to maintain all the properties of cup products in a very simple chain product like that one, but I was wrong...

Another question is probably easy. Can you enlighten me on *homology cross products*? Cup products are intuitive, at least to me, since their application is stunningly easy with the front/back faces of a simplex. I cannot grasp how cross products work on a chain complex.

Reading Hatcher (Ch. 3.B page 268) and Munkres (Ch. 7, page 346) didn't help. I still cannot figure out how to actually compute a cross product. In particular, I cannot understand what happens if I restrict myself to a *single* complex, so having $\times : C_k(K, G) \times C_\ell(K, G) \rightarrow C_{k+\ell}(K, G)$, obviously, with $K$ being a $k+\ell$ (simplicial) complex.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the cup product?